# sqlite c++ put and retrieve blob

Tags: c++, sqlite, blob

i finally figured out how to read a binary into ram, then write it somewhere with

```
ifstream::pos_type size;
char * memblock;

/* ...bunch of stuff... */

ifstream infile(filename1.c_str(), ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
ofstream outfile(filename2.c_str(), ios::out|ios::binary);

if (infile.is_open())
{
    size = infile.tellg();
    memblock = new char [size]; //request mem allocation of that size

    infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);  //move to begining
    infile.read(memblock, size);//read file
    infile.close();             //close file

    outfile.write(memblock,size);
    outfile.close();
}
```

i have also tested that `outfile.write(memblock,sizeof(memblock));` works totally fine
SO i applied this with sqlite and did it step by step by storing it in the database with `sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt,2,memblock,size,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);` and everything else that goes along with it like hte `step` and etc. I'm able to retrieve the data from the table with

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,"SELECT Data, Size FROM table1",-1,&stmt,0);
sqlite3_step(stmt);

char * result = (char * )sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,0);
outfile.write(result,size);
```

this also works fine.
However when i use `outfile.write(result,sizeof(result));` instead, it doesnt work
doing `size - sizeof(result)` gets me large number (i was just looking for a 0 or not mostly)
so i dont really know WHERE its going wrong. is it inputting the data into the database wrong?
am i retrieving the data wrong?

i even tried adding another column and then inserting the `size` and using that but didn't seem to work for some reason

Comment: You have a memory leak. `memblock` is never deleted.

Comment: memory leak? i never use `memblock` again when im dealing with the sqlite data, only on the input. unless youre talking about generally...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have also tested that `outfile.write(memblock,sizeof(memblock));` works totally fine

This is exceedingly unlikely. `sizeof(memblock) == sizeof(char*) == 4` (or perhaps 8). It does **not** report the size of the block of data that `memblock` points to. `sizeof(result)` doesn't work for the same reason.

Note that you don't need to store the size of the blob as a separate column in the database. SQLite keeps track of the size; you can retrieve it with `sqlite3_column_bytes`.

Comment: sizeof memblock shouldnt work? what you said makes sense but its strange that it did work lol.
How do i use `sqlite3_column_bytes`? i remember seeing something about its for an "open blob" or something but im not really trying to do anything to the data while its in the table, just take it out. Maybe i should just open and close it?

Comment: Somehow, you are fooling yourself into believing it works. Look more closely. Do  `cout << sizeof(memblock);`, that might prove illuminating.

Comment: It's simple: `int size = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 0);`

Comment: YAY i swear i did this like three times and i kept outputting litarly...the size to a file (checked with hex editor)

Comment: Now im outputting the file with `outfile.write((char*)sqlite3_column_blob(stmt,0),sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt,0));` and yea alot of weird stuff with the `sizeof()`function, although its just a pointer, it worked before so maybe i either misread or something else dumb happened.